# How to validate signature pad empty or not in android?

Tags: android, digital-signature, android-security

How to validate signature pad empty or not in android?

How can I check if a signature is completely blank, i.e. all its pixels are transparent?

I must avoid  an `x-y` loop on every pixel.

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Show us what you already tried and what is not working.

Answer (score 1):

```
//globally
private boolean isSignatured = false;

//onCreate
mSignaturePad.setOnSignedListener(new SignaturePad.OnSignedListener() {
@Override
public void onSigned() {
   //Event triggered when the pad is signed
    isSignatured = true;
}

@Override
public void onClear() {
   //Event triggered when the pad is cleared
}
});

//in your on click
if(isSignatured){
    //do next process
}else{
    //intimate to sign
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code,it's working

```
if(!signature_view.isBitmapEmpty()) {
   saveNotes(signature_view);
  }
```